# Azure AD B2C Authentication - Restrict to only certain customer users

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an ASP.Net core web application and integrated authentication using the Azure AD B2C Tenant/Application. I'm able to authenticate and get the user claims in my web application.

But what I additionally want is to allow only certain customer users access the web application. I want to do this at the B2C Tenant itself. Right now any B2C customer user can sign in. Any help, ideas, insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may know there is an [Manage user assignment for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal) feature in Azure Active Directory. But it's not available in Azure B2C.

Currently the recommended way to control the access in Azure B2C is [defining custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow) and check the claims in token.

If the expected claim is included, you allow the user to continue.

Comment: I'm aware of the AAD user assignment part but looking for same/similar feature for B2C. I hate to add custom attribute for each application.

Comment: @VivekN Unfortunately there is no same/similar feature for B2C currently.